# Is the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ open, closed or neither?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

> I am given the subset $A=\{(x, \sin(1/x)) | x>0\} \bigcup \{(0,y) | y \in [-1,1] \}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the standard Euclidean metric

I came to the conclusion that it is not open because for $x>$[some finite value>0], we clearly just have a 1 dimensional line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, about which none of the points have an open ball of finite radius that is entirely contained within the subspace (line).

To determine if it is closed, I have to consider whether its complement is open. On the one hand it is true that any point I can *state* in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (i.e. write the numbers down for) that is not contained in $A$, I can find an open ball around that is not contained in $A$, even if it is very close to $x=0$. I also cannot think of how I would construct a sequence in$A$ whose limit point is not in $A$, and of course if $L(A)=A$, then $A$ is closed.

However I am having trouble reconciling this with the fact that the sinusoidal squiggles become infintitely close as $x\rightarrow 0$. It is easy to show that the distance between adjacent intersections of the $y=0$ axis $\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. It makes it feel like the complement shouldn't really be open...

Would I be correct in thinking that the fact that the definition hinges on *stating* a *specific* element in the set or complement is the significant point here?

Also, I wanted to verify that $A=\{(x,y)| x\in \mathbb{Q}, y^n = x $ such that $ n\in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: In your second set definition, at the end of your question, is $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: What have you already proven? Have you proven that a set is closed if it contains all of its limit points? Have you proven the continuous image of a compact set is compact? Have you proven that the union of two closed sets is closed? Or are you only able to prove that it is closed by showing that its complement is open?

Comment: @TheoBendit They are both in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I am following a course on 'metric and topological spaces' and so far have only completed the 'metric' part and started the 'topological spaces' part. So I know and have proven that a set is closed iff it contains all of its limit points in a metric space, and I know that the union of finitely many closed sets is closed. I have not yet looked formally considered compactness, and can see it comes later in the notes. Looking at the defintion now, it includes the notion of 'boundedness', which I think is relevant to my problem. I will look at this now so that I can understand

Comment: answers referring to compactness.

Comment: @21joanna12 you may want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve ;-)

Comment: @ComplexFlo !! Thank you! I did think there was something significant in this! Definitely a good example to have come across in learning about metric and topological spaces :)

Answer (score 1):

The set $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to consider any $(x',y') \in \overline{A}$. We shall show that $(x',y') \in A$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a metric space, there exists a sequence $(x_n,y_n) \in A$ such that $(x_n,y_n) \to (x',y')$, i.e. $x_n \to x'$ and $y_n \to y'$. Since all $x_n \ge 0$, we obtain $x' \ge 0$. Moreover, all $y_n \in [-1,1]$ so that $y' \in [-1,1]$.

Case 1: $x' > 0$. Then $x_n > 0$ for all but finitely many $n$. We can assume w.l.o.g. that all $x_n > 0$, hence $y_n = \sin(1/x_n)$. The continuity of $\sin(1/x)$ on $(0,\infty)$ implies $
y_n \to \sin(1/x')$. By the uniqueness of limits we see that $y' = \sin(1/x')$, hence $(x',y') \in A$.

Case 2: $x' = 0$. Then $(x',y') = (0,y') \in A$.

Concerning your second set $A$ I understand that you mean $y^n = x$ *for some* $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Clearly $A \subset \mathbb{Q} \times\mathbb{Q}$. If $A$ were open, then $A = int(A) \subset int(\mathbb{Q} \times\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$ which is absurd. Next consider any sequence $(y_m) \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $y_m \to \sqrt{2}$. Then $(y_m,y_m) \in A$, but $(y_m,y_m) \to (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) \notin A$ which shows that $A$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $A$ is not open.

The set $A$ is also closed.  As far as I can tell, there is no straightforward argument which follows directly from the definitions.  Here is a possible alternative:

Recall that if $f(x,y)$ is continuous, then the set $f(x,y)=0$ is closed.  Now consider the function $f(x,y)=x\sin(1/x)-xy$.  It's fairly straightforward to show that $x\sin(1/x)$ is continuous, despite the squiggle.  Then to solve $f(x,y)=0$, note that $0=(\sin(1/x)-y)x$, so either $x$=0 or $\sin(1/x)-y=0$.  Thus the zero set of $f(x)$ is $A\cup\{(x,0)|y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.  Now $A$ is the intersection of this set with the closed set $\{(x,y)|x\in\mathbb{R},y\in[-1,1]\}$.  Recall that the intersection of two closed sets is closed.  Thus $A$ is closed.

Since your second question is unrelated to the first, I would recommend deleting it and reposting it as a second question.

Answer (score 0):

You can show directly that the complement of $A$ is open: let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$.
Case 1. $x<0$: the disc around $(x,y)$ with radius $|x|$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$
Case 2. $x=0$: then $y>1$ or $y<-1$; let your radius be $y-1$ or $-1-y$ respectively
Case 3. $x>0$: then $y\neq\sin\frac1x$, let $\epsilon=\frac12|y-\sin\frac1x|$ and take $\delta>0$ such that $|z-x|<\delta$ implies $|\sin\frac1z-\sin\frac1x|<\epsilon$. The disc of radius $\min\{\epsilon,\delta\}$ around $(x,y)$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$.

As to the second set: $(0,0)$ is in the set but not in its interior: consider points of the form $(r,0)$ with irrational $r$; $(\pi,\pi)$ is in the closure of the set but not in the set itself.